# Is .tif image multipage or not?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple question (I hope it is simple for someone). How could I recognize is `.tif` (or `.tiff`) image contains two or more pages, or it is just one image (one "page"). I use .NET. For what? I have an image as input and should process it in some way, and if image consists of several images - choose one method, just one image - another method. I am waiting for any *free* solution (it can be just .net or any free third-party library). I don't need to split tiff or any other good thing, just something like

```
Boolean isMultipage = SomeLibrary.IsTifMultipage(filePath);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a method that would determine that for..Perhaps something like this?

```
public bool IsMultipage(string fileName) 
{ 
    using (Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(fileName)) 
    {       
        FrameDimension frameDimensions = new FrameDimension(imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);      

        return imageFile.GetFrameCount(frameDimensions) > 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why not `imageFile.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);`? then it reads 'clearer' and you 'save' a line.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder thanks, it also works